# Java JsonObject miss the fields when convert object to Json

Tags: java, json

In java-json.jar i try to convert the object to json. My issue is I have one array list which is set in Object but when i convert this into json it does not show the list in Json.

```
JSONObject facebookJson = new JSONObject(facebook);
       user = facebookJson.toString();
```

When i debug i saw that list is set in facebook object.  I am wondering why this happens

Comment: Please provide more code. Which fields are you talking about. What is a 'facebook'?

Comment: Do you have getters for every field in the `facebook` object?

Comment: I have setter only for every fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object `facebook` needs a getter for every field. Take a look to the documentation:

> public JSONObject(java.lang.Object bean)
>
> Construct a JSONObject from
>   an Object using bean getters. It reflects on all of the public methods
>   of the object. For each of the methods with no parameters and a name
>   starting with "get" or "is" followed by an uppercase letter, the
>   method is invoked, and a key and the value returned from the getter
>   method are put into the new JSONObject. The key is formed by removing
>   the "get" or "is" prefix. If the second remaining character is not
>   upper case, then the first character is converted to lower case. For
>   example, if an object has a method named "getName", and if the result
>   of calling object.getName() is "Larry Fine", then the JSONObject will
>   contain "name": "Larry Fine".

You can also use other constructor of the JSONObject, passing it the name of the field in case that this field is accessible from where you want to create the JSON (careful here, it can break encapsulation):

> public JSONObject(java.lang.Object object,
>                     java.lang.String[] names)
>
> Construct a JSONObject from an Object, using reflection to find the public members. The
>   resulting JSONObject's keys will be the strings from the names array,
>   and the values will be the field values associated with those keys in
>   the object. If a key is not found or not visible, then it will not be
>   copied into the new JSONObject.